# ActiveRecord Refusing to Change Ports

Tags: sql-server, ruby, database, activerecord, jdbc

Using the following code:

```
require 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
require 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter'
require_relative 'sqljdbc42.jar'

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
                      :adapter => 'jdbcmssql',
                      :driver => 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver',
                      :username => 'pcp_admin',
                      :password => 'pcp_admin01',
                      :port => 1021,
                      :database => 'pcp',
                      :url => 'jdbc:sqlserver://OHNALWBD0145.nwie.net',
)
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
```

This is all the correct information to be used. However, when I try to run this, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host OHNALWBD0145.nwie.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
```

I find this error message to be particularly odd, as I had input the port into the method as 1021, and NOT 1433. I'm not sure why it is trying to use port 1433. I know it's the default port for SQLServer, but I should be overriding that, or so I thought.

Comment: Put the port in the JDBC url, so `:url => 'jdbc:sqlserver://OHNALWBD0145.nwie.net:1021'`

Comment: That did work, thank you!